# Laravel action controller not being called from ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5, datatables

I have a view where I use blade and jquery.datatables. 
After populate a table with data comming from the BD, I want to get and send the selected rows values. 
For that, I created a jquery code using a ajax request.

```
$('#enviar').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();

var table = $('#tabelaContactos').DataTable();  
var rows = $('tr.selected');
var rowData =  table.rows(rows).data();

var dataArr = [];
$.each($(rowData),function(key,value){  
    //getting the 3 column 
    dataArr.push(value[2]);

});

$.ajax({
    url:'{{ route("criarSms") }}',
    data: {'dados':dataArr},
    type:'GET',     
    success:function(msg)
    {
        $("#numeroT").text(msg);
    }
});
```

});

after that, I defined a route to my controller action, that will respond to the ajax request.

```
Route::get('mensagem/createMessage','MensagemController@createMessage')->name('criarSms');
```

two things are happen here, first my controller action is not being called, and second the response is always the same view.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved.
The problem was due to the order of the Routes.

> Route::get('mensagem/{id}','MensagemController@index')->name('envio');
> Route::get('mensagem/createMessage','MensagemController@createMessage')->name('criarSms');

I had a route to the index method in the same controller, don't know why but laravel was using that route always, even if I call the "**criarSms**" defined after the "**envio**" route.

I changed the order and is working.

> ```
> Route::get('mensagem/createMessage','MensagemController@createMessage')->name('criarSms');
> ```
>
> Route::get('mensagem/{id}','MensagemController@index')->name('envio');